# PHP/MySql search one value in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search

I'm trying to get values from my usermeta table depending on a certain provence.
I live in the Netherlands. We have 12 provences here and I want to select all users who live in a certain provence. So I added a field to the user database that is named 'provincies'. A button with a value `<a href="results.php?provincie=provencename"`
tells me who to select based upon the value from the url.

This isn't difficult. The problem is that users can have multiple provences.
So the meta_key `provincie` fields hold the meta_value `friesland','groningen','drenthe'`

So now I need to search if the added value from the url is in the database meta_value.

```
$provincie_array = "friesland','groningen','drenthe"; 
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
          WHERE meta_key='provincie' 
          AND meta_value IN ('".$provincie_array."')";
```

I think this is right. However PHP and MySql beg to differ.

Can anybody see what I'm missing here?

-EDIT-

```
$provincie = $_GET['provincie'];
                global $wpdb;
                //$query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='provincie' AND meta_value IN ('".$provincie_array."')";

$provincie_array = array('friesland','groningen','drenthe','noordholland','flevoland','overijssel','zuidholland','utrecht','gelderland','zeeland','noordbrabant','limburg'); 
$provincie_check = '';
foreach ($provincie_array as $value) {
    $provincie_check[]="`meta_value` LIKE '%[{$value}]%'";
}
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
          WHERE meta_key='provincie' 
          AND ( ".implode(' OR ',$provincie_check)." )";
          $personen = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: The last singe quote from the word drenthe, in the $provincie_array should not be there.

Comment: True, typo because the list is longer. However problem is still there :-)

Comment: @MySQLRockstar The starting and ending quotes are in the `IN` function

Comment: Don't use single quotes at all. $provincie_array = "friesland,groningen,drenthe";

Comment: is the field "meta_value " a string ? (char or varchar). I mean do you store multiple values into one field as string ?

Comment: yes the following is a actual copy/paste from the database: `friesland','groningen','drenthe','noordholland','flevoland','overijssel','zuidholland','utrecht','gelderland','zeeland','noordbrabant','limburg`

Comment: @Fred-ii- The question was allready edited. It is right now.

Comment: @BishopBarber I've deleted my comments. *cheers*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work... :)

For @Interactive: You set $find_provincie = $_GET['provincie']; and that's it.

```
$find_provincie = 'groningen'; //look for 1
$find_provincie = array('friesland','groningen'); //look for multiple


if(is_array($find_provincie)){
    $provincie_check = '';
    foreach ($find_provincie as $value) {
        $provincie_check[]="`meta_value` LIKE '%[{$value}]%'";
    }
    $provincie_check=implode(' OR ',$provincie_check);
}else{
    $provincie_check = "`meta_value` LIKE '%[{$find_provincie}]%'";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM usermeta WHERE meta_key='provincie' AND ( ".$provincie_check." )";
```

Tested and working if you store each element in brackets like: [groningen][drenthe]

Comment: No it doesn't. No matter where I click I always see the same person

Comment: It does work. Tested in local enviroment: http://s2.postimg.org/h0269r42x/Screen_Shot_20150326160332.png check you code :) maybe it's the same person because you're checking only 1 returned line and not foreach'ing them all?

Comment: You didn't read my question right. You have every provence in a different row while I have multiple provences in a single table row. And I use a for loop to get them all :-)

Comment: You're right, I missed that. The solution would be to write all provinces in the meta_value like: [friesland][groningen] and so on. Each value in brackets like that. then you would do the new query I wrote in my asnwer.

Comment: I'll try that. Do I need to seperate the [] with a ,

Comment: No. Give me a min to check the query to make sure it will be alright for you.

Comment: Hell I'll give you 5 mins :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you added a province table as well as a junction table between your user and province tables?

Comment: Oeps. I was happy to early. Almost there. The result.php page has a paramater added to it. `?provincie=friesland`. Only the users who live in `friesland` should be shown. Now just everybody is shown :-)

Comment: Can you show how you make the $provincie_array from $_GET? Or just post more code in your question for more clearence :)

Comment: You're using everything all wrong :) $provincie_array contains 12 values which means these are all the possible values. the $provincie_array should contain only value you're looking for. so the solution would be $provincie_array = $_GET['provincie']; and the way we made the query is that you can search for multiple provinces and I see you're only trying to look for one? or am I wrong on this?

Comment: Do you want me to rewrite the query to search for only 1 province or you'll go with multiple province search? :)

Comment: Would you? Really? Wow that is amazing.

Comment: You are the best!!!! Thank you so much for your time and effort. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
$provincie_array = array("friesland","groningen","drenthe"); 
$query = "SELECT * 
      FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
      WHERE meta_key='provincie' 
      AND meta_value IN ('".implode(",", $provincie_array)."')";
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and what have you done to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your database sstructure is not Ideal. 
If you store multiple values in a field you need to search a string.

Try Using " like " statements (not the best, not the fastest) but ok in your case unless you decide to change the database structure.

your query should look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta
          WHERE meta_key='provincie'
          AND (
                meta_value LIKE '%friesland%'
                OR meta_value LIKE '%groningen%'
                OR meta_value LIKE '%drenthe%'
          )";
```

So in php you should do something like this:

```
$provincie_array = array('friesland','groningen','drenthe');

$querypart = "meta_value LIKE '%".implode("%' OR meta_value LIKE '%", $provincie_array)."%'";

$query = "SELECT *
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta
          WHERE
            meta_key='provincie'
            AND (".$querypart.")";
```

Comment: No luck. Still gives me one person no matter the provence. Hoever I didn't change the datbase what exactly the same is as the `$provincie_array`

Comment: There would be a huge problem is the provinces have similiar beggings or endigns. Lets say you have 'drenthe' and 'drentheng': if you search for 'drenthe' you will find both 'drenthe' and 'drentheng'. I don't think this is a problem for @Interactive , but this method has a huge bug. You could see my answer on how to make it without a bug like this.